# How can I get the filename of each file in a certain folder?

Tags: c#

I want to make a list with all the text files names that are stored in this directory: `"/Users/myname/TESTFOLDER"` But I just need the filename, I don't want to add the full path of the files in my list `Filenamelist`.

My code always adds the full path of the files to the list:

```
     List<string> Filenamelist = new List<string>();
     userDir = "/Users/myname/TESTFOLDER";
     var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(userDir, "*.txt");
     foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
     {
         Filenamelist.Add(currentFile);
     }
```

How can I only add the filename to the list?

Comment: Where do you get FileList from

Comment: Couldn't you cut userDir from each currentFile string as you load them into Filenamelist?

Comment: @Jawad It was just a typo. I changed FileList to txtFiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to select file name using `Path.GetFileName` that Returns the file name and extension of the specified path string and exists in namespace `System.IO` for more info you can check its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8).after getting files using `EnumerateFiles` function that returns an `IEnumerable` which can be lazily evaluated for more info you can check its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.8).

if you want to get sub directories files set search option to be `SearchOption.AllDirectories` because The default value is `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly` for more info check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.searchoption?view=netframework-4.8).

```
 using System.IO; 

    userDir = "/Users/myname/TESTFOLDER";
    List<string> Filenamelist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(userDir,"*.txt").Select(file => Path.GetFileName(file)).ToList();
```

Comment: @Steve thanks for your note, solution has been updated

Comment: If you add `.ToList()`, the *laziness* is gone.

Comment: @Jimi .ToList() will resolve the whole statement after filtering and projection to assign it to the final list when I mention lazily evaluation I was talking about EnumerateFiles function,I am open to any enhancement you suggest.

Comment: `.ToList()` causes the enumeration to materialize, before the assignment. So the (hypothetical) benefits are mute. It's not a *bad thing*. If you need the results right away, you have materialize the collection anyway. Different story if you're looping the collection using the enumerator. It's just a note for possible watchers: *don't expect lazy (pseudo-async) enumeration here*.

Comment: @Jimi I totally agree with you but I made it like this according to the question code statement because I don't have the remaining part of the code how this list or enumeration will be used